# How to detect if IIS HTTP Authentication has authenticated a request in ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, iis, basic-authentication

I am doing URL normalization in my app, but I don't want it to take effect for my local dev server (easy, I use Request.IsLocal). But I also want to disable normalization on my semi-public staging server, which is protected from prying eyes by IIS HTTP authentication.

So how can I detect whether a request has been authenticated by IIS already? (Putting some code in Application_BeginRequest).

Doing some research it doesn't seem safe to just look at the presence of Authorization header because it might be bogus information sent to a page that doesn't require authentication and IIS wouldn't reject the request.

Comment: Are you using Persist-Auth? Read more about this, and I think it should answer a bit of your query. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/benjaminperkins/archive/2011/10/31/kerberos-authpersistnonntlm-authentication-request-based-vs-session-based-authentication.aspx?Redirected=true

Comment: You need to be more specific on which application pool mode you want to discuss, as clearly for classic mode ASP.NET pipeline won't see the request unless it has been authenticated already by IIS pipeline.